# mostrar datos en una ventana modal

Tags: php, bootstrap

Hola tengo problemas para mostrar los datos de una tabla en una modal. Tengo una lista la cual lleno con un arreglo de php llamado resultadoPacientes esto es una array, y tengo una modal que es un formulario en donde al darle la segunda opcion deben enviarse los datos que se muestran en el modal. pero no cuadran los valores correspondientes

```
<table class="example table table-hover col-md-10">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>position</th>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Acción</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($resultadosPaciente as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value->ProdCodigo ; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value->ProdNombre ; ?></td>
           <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalCanje" data-codigoCanje="<?php echo $value->ProdCodigo ; ?>" data-tipo="normal">Estado</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

al momento de darle al boton de estado se me despliega el siguiente modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCanje" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Producto de regalo</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 <form id="form-canje-premio">
                  <input type="hidden" name="codigoCanje" id="codigoCanje">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="nombreProducto">Nombre</label>
                      <input
                      type="text" readonly autocomplete="off" class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $value->ProdNombre; ?>" name="nombreProducto" id="nombreProducto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="activo">Activo</label>
                      <input
                        type="text" readonly class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $value->ProdActivo; ?>" name="activo" id="activo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="nombreProducto">Cantidad de Premio</label>
                      <input
                       type="text" readonly class="form-control" value="<?php echo  $value->Bono; ?>" name="cantPremio" id="cantPremio">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                       <input type="radio" name="estadoCanje" id="estadoCanje" value="1" required> Entrega Inmediata<br>
                       <input type="radio" name="estadoCanje" id="estadoCanje" value="2" required> No hay disponibilidad producto
                       <input type="hidden" name="precioUnitario" id="precioUnitario" value="<?php echo  $value->ProdCosto; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="codigoCanje" id="codigoCanje" value="<?php echo $value->CodigoDescuento; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="productoId" id="productoId" value="<?php echo  $value->ProdCodigo; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="tarjetaId" id="tarjetaId" value="<?php echo  $value->TarjetaID; ?>">
                    </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
              </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

el problema es que no muestra los valores correspondientes o bueno solo muestra un valor
[image: tabla]
[image: modal]

Comment: O bien necesitas usar javascript para solucionar eso (ya sea con ajax o sin ajax) o bien necesitas crear tantos modales como filas tenga tu tabla con los datos de cada uno y con su id unico.  Lo que prefieras, pero tal como lo tienes ahora tan solo te mostrará el primero de todos seguramente siempre.

Comment: ok amigo pero puedo renderizar ese modal con ajax?

Comment: es que no se como pasarle un identificador al boton que llama al modal

Comment: Si, claro, a ver, el ajax lo unico que hace es mandarle información al script de PHP de turno, y éste es el encargado de montar la salida (al igual que ya estás haciendo ahora en PHP, pero en lugar de montarla entera tan solo necesitas montar lo del modal que variará en función de los datos que le has enviado).  Una vez el PHP ha montado la salida y el ajax recibe la respuesta, tan solo es cuestión de lanzar el modal recibido que ya contendrá los datos correctos.

Comment: El otro tema del identificador (que no tiene que ver con la solución ajax, pero para que lo sepas) ya lo estás haciendo cuando usas esto: `data-target="#modalCanje"` pues `modalCange` es el id del modal que tienes actualmente con los datos rellenados del primer registro que ha cogido (y no del resto)

Comment: no pero eso es para el modal es decir para mostrarlo, ya teniendo que identifica a cada fila puedo obtener los resultados en cada modal, en teoría

Comment: Quizas no me has entendido, pero ya te he dicho antes que si, pero con javascript (con o sin ajax).   Con javascript necesitas crear una función que lo haga capturando el evento click del botón de cada fila con addEventListener() y luego recoger los datos de la fila y ponerlos en el modal. Con ajax evitas eso y lo haces desde el PHP y luego tan solo debes lanzarlo con ellos.  Si eres más ducho en PHP que con javscript entonces te conviene ajax, si es al contrario entonces con javascript puro.